# PHP call super parent method

Tags: php, oop

I'm not sure at all if there is such a term but here is what I want to do

```
class A {
    function a($a) {
        return $a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function a($a) {
        return parent::a('B' . $a);
    }
}

class C extends B {
    function a($a) {
        return superparent::a('C' . $a);
    }
}

$c = new C();
echo $c->a('C'); // "CC"
```

I want to bypass all medial classes and call the function on the parent where it was defined for the first time - is this possible?

Comment: This feels like a code smell. The class C shouldn't know anything about the class A. It shouldn't even know that it exists. You should do different methods instead, if they are doing different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, and it's a terrible idea. All your class `C` knows is that it extends `B`. It cannot know nor should it know what, if anything, `B` extends. `C` cannot count on `B` extending anything, nor should it be aware of specific methods of that grand parent and their implementation details. You may be refactoring `B` tomorrow to extend another class, or to extend no class at all. Code would start breaking left and right if you established such three-class-crossover dependencies.

Classes should only interact with peers they're directly associated with, either through inheritance or dependency injection.

Just logically speaking: `B` *adds* something necessary to the behaviour of `A` to "make it a `B`", and `C` adds something to make it a `C`. `C` builds on `B`, so anything `B` does `C` should do as well. Having `C` "jump over" `B` back to `A` suggests that your logic and responsibility assignment is mixed up in your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Despite of any Engineering Software complaint (what you are trying to do is something that must be achieved by some other approach) I thought that both my examples are suposed to work:

## Using a trait:

```
<?php

trait Bypass_trait {
    public function super_ref() {
        return parent::super_ref();
    }
}

class A {
    function a($a) {
        return $a;
    }

    function super_ref() {
      return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    use Bypass_trait;

    function a($a) {
        return $this->super_ref()->a('B' . $a);
    }
}

class C extends B {
    use Bypass_trait;

    function a($a) {
        return $this->super_ref()->a('C' . $a);
    }
}

$c = new C();
echo $c->a('C'); // "CC"
```

## Using an interface:

```
<?php

interface Bypass {
  public function super_ref();
}

class A implements Bypass {
    function a($a) {
        return $a;
    }

    function super_ref() {
      return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A implements Bypass {
    function a($a) {
        return $this->super_ref()->a('B' . $a);
    }

    function super_ref() {
      return parent::super_ref();
    }
}

class C extends B implements Bypass {
    function a($a) {
        return $this->super_ref()->a('C' . $a);
    }

    function super_ref() {
      return parent::super_ref();
    }
}

$c = new C();
echo $c->a('C'); // "CC"
```

Answer (score -1):

i thing you can make "A" as abstract, then let b and c override it

Comment: That's a possible workaround to the class design, but hardly answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose which parent method you call with `A::a('C' . $a)`.

When calling a parent function like this, it does not call it statically, just like `parent::a()`.

Comment: No it does not call it statically, just like `parent::a()`. You can try it by using `$this` call inside the function declared in class A.

Comment: While this is all true technically, it's still a terrible thing to do in practice.